# Getting 403 status while fetching data from ASP.Net Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-web-api

I am fetching WEB.API from xamarin forms application.Web API created in .Net Web API. But i am getting error

```
{StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'ModSecurity Action', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Sat, 02 Sep 2017 07:59:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2684
}}
```

Same URL is giving proper output from Browser and postman also.
I am using below code to fetch web api. I am not getting exactly what happening.

```
string RestUrl = "http://msystemtest.msystem.co/api/Users?userId={0}&pass={1}";

            var uri = new Uri(string.Format(RestUrl, uid, pass));
            string resp = string.Empty;

            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

            string statHold = string.Empty;
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(content);
            }
```

If "http://msystemtest.msystem.co/api/Users?userId=test&pass=1" this URL directly run from browser and from postman its giving proper output.

Comment: Have you checked the `uri ` result? Maybe the format has wrong input parameters

Comment: Format is right. I have tested URI result directly. Its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the server does not like you reading this from a non browser. Here is code to emulate a browser from a console application:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");

                var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://msystemtest.msystem.co/api/Users?userId=test&pass=1").Result;
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine from console application. But when I try to implement from Xamarin Forms application it is giving same status.

Comment: Try using fiddler to check that the Xamarin Forms application does not overwrite the user-agent heading

Comment: Its working fine by slight changes in code. Thanks for your assist.